# Sum certain indice values in MultiDimensional Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sum

I have the following:

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => Array 
    ( 
        [department] => Central>ACME>BusDev 
        [Total_Staff] => 4 
        [Total_Resp] => 0 
    ) 
)
```

There are over 150 of these within the array.

I can easily sum, for example, `Total_Staff` and `Total_Resp` using something like:

```
foreach($arr as $num => $values) {
    $sum_staff += $values[ 'Total_Staff' ];
    $sum_resp += $values[ 'Total_Resp' ];
}
```

However what I need to do is sum only elements of the array, for example I need to sum `Total_Staff` and `Total_resp` that lies between `indexes` 0 and 7 or 12 and 58.

Not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need

```
foreach($arr as $num => $values) {
    if(($num >= 0 && $num <= 7) || ($num >= 12 && $num <= 58))
        $sum += $values[ 'Total_Staff' ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `for` loop would be the way to solve this:

```
 $start = 12;
 $end = 58;
 $sum_total_staff = 0;
 $sum_total_resp = 0;

 for( $i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++ ) {       
     $sum_total_staff += $arr[$i]["Total_Staff"];   
     $sum_total_resp += $arr[$i]["Total_Resp"];   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Id say use these 2 function to slice & merge the arrays. It will get 8 arrays from which are between indexes 0-7 (with 0 and 7 included) and same with the second one. If you want without 0 and 7, it would be with arguments 1, 6, so `array_slide($arr, 1, 6);` and so on.

```
$new_arr1 = array_slice($arr, 0, 8);
$new_arr2 = array_slice($arr, 12, 47);
$arr = array_merge($new_arr1, $new_arr2);
```